# How to know which files have been modified to fix a bug starting from a git commit?

Tags: java, git, versioning, jgit

I'm working on a Java project and I need to understand which files have been modified to fix bugs.

The versioning of the project I'm working on is managed through Git.

Until now I have been able to get the commit that was made to fix the bug, however starting from this how can I get the files that have been modified?

I probably have to run the `diff` between the commit that was made to fix the bug and another commit, but what is this other commit?
Can I get it by going up the commit graph? If so, how?

All this has to be done in Java ... to interact with GitHub I'm using the `jgit` library.

Comment: *All this has to be done in Java* why?

Comment: Did you read these post? They seem to answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27361538/2986905, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39935160/2986905, https://stackoverflow.com/q/31325613/2986905, https://stackoverflow.com/q/28852698/2986905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `git diff` with `--name-only` flag comparing two commits to check the changes between them.

For example, if you want to compare the changes in the last 5 commits you can use HEAD reference by doing:

`git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~5`

where the first commit reference is the newest one.

If you want to compare the changed files from a specific commit with the HEAD commit, you can get it by doing:

`git diff --name-only HEAD 8614c3d70397f03ab504de8d23e8255d52fa3ed1`

where 8614c3d70397f03ab504de8d23e8255d52fa3ed1 is your commit hash by example.

### For your application specifically

Since you want to check the file that was changed in one specific commit, you can do using the same logic by doing:

`git diff --name-only COMMIT_HASH COMMIT_HASH~1`

So if the bugfix commit has the hash `8614c3d70397f03ab504de8d23e8255d52fa3ed1` for example, you can check the files changed in this commit by doing:

`git diff --name-only 8614c3d70397f03ab504de8d23e8255d52fa3ed1 8614c3d70397f03ab504de8d23e8255d52fa3ed1~1`

Answer (score 0):

To see the files ghat were modified on a revision you can do

```
git show --name-status some-revision
```

You can also specify `--name-only` instead of `--name-status`

`git diff` also works but it's mostly used for ranges because if you want to use diff and only provide a single revision as a param, you end up comparing with your current working tree so you end up having to pass in 2 params when, as in your case, you want to check files modified by a single revision.